# Sparkle Updater: How could I use sparkle to install an already downloaded update?

Tags: cocoa, cocoa-touch, xamarin.mac, sparkle, netsparkle

I have developed a Mac OS X app, and I have also written the update logic for this app. Basically, my app can detect if an update exists and it downloads the update to the User's local download directory.

Now, I want Sparkle to install this downloaded update - How could I do that ? I simply want to provide the 'downloaded update's location' to sparkle and I want sparkle to install the update for me.

Any help is appreciated ! Thank you !